# Reading a text file with multiple delimiters and matrices of different lengths

Tags: matlab, text, text-files

I'm trying to read text files that contain multiple arrays of different (but known) sizes.

I know the following about the files:

Each file has a matrix of size m x n, in the format as in this example:

```
[[0.05,0.15,0.25,0.35,0.0]
[0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25],
[0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25],
[0.05,0.1,0.5,0.6,0.1]]
```

This is followed by a matrix of size p x 1:

```
[3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6]
```

And finally a scalar (no square brackets here)

```
3
```

The simplest way I've found to do this is the following:

1. strip the brackets from the text files (using a language more appropriate than MATLAB!)
2. Use `data = importdata()` to read the file. This results in one array, with the last two rows containing the p x 1 matrix and the scalar (with some NaNs because of the difference between matrix sizes)
3. Pull out the data, `A = data(1:m, 1:n); b = data(m+1,1:p); c = data(m+2,1);`

This seems quite clunky. I can copy and paste the 2-dimensional matrix (with brackets included) into the MATLAB command window, and MATLAB knows how to parse it. This makes me think there is a more elegant way to do this with one MATLAB function.

The whole example text file:

```
[[0.05,0.15,0.25,0.35,0.0],
[0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25],
[0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25],
[0.05,0.1,0.5,0.6,0.1]]
[3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6]
3
```

Comment: Your first line has 4 elements; the next three have five.  I've added a 0.0 to the first line for my local sample.

Comment: Which "language more appropriate than MATLAB (for text processing)" are you using?  Does it have MEX support?

Comment: FWIW, to strip `[`, `]` from a string in Matlab, you can use: `regexprep(str,'[\[\]]','')`.   See also `strrep`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable passing the contents of this file into an `eval` command, this seems to be the most straightforward method:

```
 %Read in the full file as a string  (this is often easier than handling the file directly)
fid = fopen('somefile.txt');
str = fread(fid,inf,'uint8=>char')';
fclose(fid);

str = ['{' str '}'];  %Add braces, this will gather the arrays when evaluated.
data = eval(str);     %Evaluate
```

This tickles my *something-must-be-wrong* sense a little bit, as it's a pretty fragile way to handle data.  But it should work well enough for a limited data set.

My `samefile.txt` file contains the following (note I added a 0 to the first line):

```
[[0.05,0.15,0.25,0.35,0],
[0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25],
[0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25],
[0.05,0.1,0.5,0.6,0.1]]
[3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6]
3
```

After running the above, I have a `data` variable with the following contents:

```
>> data{1}
ans =
       0.05                      0.15                      0.25                      0.35                         0
       0.05                       0.1                      0.15                       0.2                      0.25
       0.05                       0.1                      0.15                       0.2                      0.25
       0.05                       0.1                       0.5                       0.6                       0.1    
>> data{2}
ans =
   3     3     4     5     5     5     5     6
>> data{3}
ans =
   3
```